# mobile safari - auto tab switching bug?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, browser-refresh

It seems Mobile Safari has some weird behaviour like auto tab switching.

Please check out the following link using Mobile Safari and then create another tab.

http://adhoc.sometwo.net/MobileSafariSucks.html

As you can see, you can't stay on other tabs. Mobile Safari always switches back to the tab with the link when it is refreshed.

Here is the simple source code I've written in that page:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Mobile Safari Sucks</title>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="#acacac" onLoad="self.focus();">
      Mobile Safari Sucks
   </body>
</html>
```

It seems `http-equiv="refresh"` and `onLoad="self.focus();"` causes this problem.

Can this be considered a bug, as Chrome and other browsers are not switching back to this tab on refresh?

One who wants to annoy his visitors, can set a very low refreshing period and ruin their browsing experience.

What could be done to save users from this unpleasant situation except deleting `self.focus();` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm this is(was) a bug, not an intended behaviour and it is fixed in iOS7.

Comment: hey, @erkanyildiz it's happening in Mac OS for me now. can you pls help on this.